# Replacing the Element with specific attribute and its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsums <font style="background-color:yellow">ipsum</font> ipsume lorem
</p>
```

how to replace the `<font>` tag with `<abbr>` so the out put will be like this.

```
 <p>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsums <abbr style="background-color:yellow">ipsum</abbr> ipsume lorem
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finds all font tags within any  p, and replaces it with an abbr with the style attribute and text copied over.

```
$("p font").each(function() {
    var font = $(this);

    var abbr = $("<abbr>", {
        style: font.attr("style"),
        text: font.text()
    });

    font.replaceWith(abbr);
});
​
```

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all `<font` and `</font` with `<abbr` and `</abbr`.

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; // assume this is the first P in the document
var p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/(<|<\/)font/g, "$1abbr")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [getAttributes plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes) to copy your attributes:

```
var attributes =$.getAttributes($(YOURTAG));
$(YOURTAG).replaceWith($('<abbr>' + YOURTAG.innerHTML + '</abbr>');
$(YOURTAG).attr(attributes);
```

Note: I'm sorry but I didn't test this one...

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
$('p').each(
     function(){
          $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(<|<\/)font/g, "$1abbr"));
     }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){
    $("font").replaceWith(function(){
        var font = $(this);
        return $("<abbr></abbr>")
            .attr("style", font.attr("style") )
            .append( font.contents() );
    });
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsums <font style="background-color:yellow">ipsum</font> ipsume lorem
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

There may be a more straightforward way but this seems to work.